# JQuery mobile - Ad rendering

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to display ads in my site which is developed using JQM. Am having a script which i added in the header:

```
<div data-role="header">

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://ad.dclick.net/adj/m.test.com;tile=1;sz=320x50;kvpos=top;adtar=;ord=" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

The above script writes the ad image to the document using document.write(). But, this is not working fine when using AJAX. Only on full page load, the ad renders.

Hope am clear on the requirement. Please help. This ad script is also in footer and content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-role="header">
  <script>
      $.get("http://ad.dclick.net/adj/m.test.com;tile=1;sz=320x50;kvpos=top;adtar=;ord=", function (data) {
       $("[data-role='header']").append(data).trigger('create');; 
 });
   </script>
</div>
```